# Blender error - Incorrect armature for type 'base_generate'

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, bones

I'm new to rigging characters in Blender and I am getting this error.

```
CONFLICT: bone ORG-cheek.T.L owned by rig ORG-face has different parent rig from ORG-face

Incorrect armature for type 'base_generate'
```

I'm not sure what it means.  I'll attach pictures to show the specific bones that I'm talking about.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the solution, although I'm fairly new to this. If you find the bone referenced in the error message, in your case cheek.T.L, and then click on the bone up from that in the chain (so travel towards the head of cheek.T.L and click on the next bone) to check its parent. When I got this message I noticed that the parent attribute for this next bone was blank. I changed it to "face" and that error disappeared. Keep on attempting to generate your rig and every bone in the face that has this problem will be highlighted one after another.

Comment: hey guys other solution in my case, i added two rigify face template rigs by accident, and then i realized that later after seeking the issue, so i deleted the one i wasnt using, and then it got generated properly....